# Why does placement-new call the standard placement operator new function?

Tags: c++, placement-new

A `placement-new` expression that takes a single argument that is a pointer to pre-allocated memory will construct an object of type `T` in that memory.

Why does it call the standard `placement-new` operator `void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, void* ptr );` since the latter does nothing and just returns its pointer argument?

```
 int x = 10;
 int* p = new(&x) int{1024};
```

- Could you explain the steps taken in the above by the compiler to construct a new `int` in the memory address of `x`?
- Why doesn't the `placement-new` expression directly construct an object at the memory address it gets as a pointer, rather than calling an operator function that does nothing and just returns its pointer argument?

Comment: `new` *operators* can be overloaded/replaced in user code. That is why a `new` *expression* calls a `new` *operator*. The default `placement-new` *operator* simply returns the pointer it is given.  A user-defined `placement-new` *operator* can do whatever it wants (logging, etc), as long as it still returns the same pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that `new (args...) T` will call `operator new(sizeof(T), args...)`, and this function is required to return `void*`. If this `operator new` call returns successfully, the object is then constructed into the memory pointed to by the return value.

This general rule is powerful enough to support both the ordinary new expression `new int` and the placement form `new (&x) int` without any special cases. These two expressions call different overloads of `operator new`, which is why the former allocates and the latter does not. No matter what, an object is constructed at the end (unless the `operator new` function failed by throwing an exception).

There is no need to have a special rule in the language that says `operator new` is not called by a placement new expression. Instead, the compiler can simply optimize the code by directly constructing the `int` object into `&x` without calling `operator new` first, since it already knows that the placement `operator new` will just return its second argument.

(Actually, the reality is a bit more complicated than this. If `T` is an array type, then `operator new[]` is called instead of `operator new`, and the compiler may request from `operator new[]` a greater amount of memory than the array will actually occupy, and adjust the returned pointer before constructing the array. There are also special rules relating to over-aligned types, and there actually is some special-casing for placement new and delete. These details are not relevant to this answer.)

Comment: "*the compiler can simply optimize the code by directly constructing the `int` object into `&x` without calling `operator new` first, since it already knows that the placement `operator new` will just return its second argument*" - are you sure about that? What about the case where `operator new` has been overloaded in user code? The compiler can't/shouldn't optimize that out.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The global *placement* `operator new` is not allowed to be overridden.